# slice a large number to three digits in javascript

Tags: javascript, math

I have a large number like 265789 or 3654389 etc. I wanted to display only first three digits of these numbers. For example, 265 or 365 in the above numbers. How to slice these large numbers to three digits in javascript.

Comment: You say you want to `slice`, so have you considered converting it to a string and using `slice`?

Comment: Is there any way to do without converting it to string

Comment: Possibly, have you attempted anything at all yourself yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use  the log<sub>10</sub> and divide the number for a shorter exponent.

```js
function getThree(n) {
    return n && Math.floor(n / Math.pow(10, Math.floor(Math.log10(n)) - 2));
}

console.log(getThree(265789));  // 256
console.log(getThree(3654389)); // 365
```

Comment: You really don't need this much math for such a simple thing.

Comment: @Olian04, do you know a solution with less math?

Answer (score 3):

You can create your own function for that using `slice` method.

```js
let sliceNumber = (num, len) => +String(num).slice(0, len);

console.log(sliceNumber(265789, 3))
console.log(sliceNumber(3654389, 4))
```